# Why doesn't visualworks highlight variables and syntax differently?

Tags: visualworks

I'm following a tutorial on how to use visualworks, and the teacher on youtube has a fancier way of seeing the code

i.e.

in this photo, his version shows (as oppose to mine in complete black)
^ in red
self in light blue
nil in pink
variables (firstname and lastname) in dark blue

[image]

How can I configure my environment to do the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out,

In the main window, you click on **System**, then select **Parcel Manager**

Under suggestions, click on **Popular**, then under its list, right click **RBCodeHighliting** then select **Load**

[image]
[image]
[image]